# curl -L to get file contents from Box through Alamofire for Swift 3

Tags: ios, curl, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to get the file contents on Box through their API in Swift.

```
curl -L https://api.box.com/2.0/files/file_id/content -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

returns the right contents, but

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/file_id/content -H "Authorization: Bearer access_token"
```

does not.
So the "-L" part seems to be critical.

So far I have

```
    let headers = [
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
        "scope": "public"
    ]

    Alamofire.request("https://api.box.com/2.0/files/file_id/content", headers: headers).responseJSON { responseFile in

        if let dataFile = responseFile.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(dataFile)")
        }
    }
```

How can I add the "-L" part to this?

The overall structure should be correct since I can successfully get the metadata for the file by removing "/content" from the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to curl manual -L/--location argument means

> If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

So, I guess, you must check response statusCode and if it will be 3xx you need to handle redirects. Check Alamofire framework documentation about that.

Also good to read about fundamentals [Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html)

Comment: Thanks! I solved it through getting the redirection url and submitting another request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a-a-m's answer, I got it working with the following code.

Note that I used responseString instead of responseJSON for the second request since the response was in a file format rather than in JSON format.

```
    Alamofire.request("https://api.box.com/2.0/files/\(file_id)/content", headers: headers).responseJSON { responseFile in

        if let newUrl = responseFile.response?.url {
            print("new link: \(newUrl)")

            //make another request using the redirection url
            Alamofire.request(newUrl).responseString { content in 

                let filecontent = content.result.value
                print (filecontent)
                self.contentText.text = filecontent
                debugPrint(contents)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```